# How do you comment a Perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, comments

How do you put comments inside a Perl regular expression?

Comment: See also [Maintaining Regular Expressions](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/01/16/regexps.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the /x modifier:

```
my $foo = "zombies are the bombies";
if ($foo =~ /
             zombie  # sorry pirates
            /x ) {
    print "urg. brains.\n";
}
```

Also see the [first question](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-can-I-hope-to-use-regular-expressions-without-creating-illegible-and-unmaintainable-code%3f) in perlfaq6.

Also it wouldn't hurt to read all of [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) while you're at it.

Comment: I should vote you down for beating me by <i>that</i> much, but I have to vote you up for the clever example.

Comment: Cheated?  Posted an empty answer, then filled it in, to get that low timestamp?  I can't think of anything else that could be called cheating.

Comment: Yeah - well, the whole "down-vote" think was a joke anyhow. I just hate when I'm midway through a clever example, and then I see that "New answers posted" flash area at the top of my browser. It's that "Newman!" moment.

Comment: Well I had the question and then I found the answer and I figured other people probably have this question too.  And its not too immoral since I don't get any reputation for anything unless someone votes me up.

Comment: you should use { } for multiline for clarity IMO.

Comment: If you want to match single spaces and comment your regex, should you use `\s`?

Answer (score 18):

Even without the /x modifier, you can enclose comments in (?# ... ):

```
my $foo = "zombies are the bombies";
if ( $foo =~ /zombie(?# sorry pirates)/ ) {
    print "urg. brains.\n";
}
```

Comment: The one problem I have with this style is that it can be tough on the eyes. Spaces before or after (?# comment) matter unless you add the /x modifier, in which case, I'm back to the /x modifier anyhow.