# How do I include an inline comment in a regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, comments, emulation, inline-code

Inline comments works when a string passed to the RegExp constructor:

```
RegExp("foo"/*bar*/).test("foo")
```

but not with an expression. Is there any equivalent or alternative in JavaScript to emulate [x-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632795/how-do-you-comment-a-perl-regular-expression) for the RegExp object?

Comment: See my `makeExtendedRegExp` function in the linked question to emulate the `x` modifier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javascript supports neither the `x` modifier, nor inline comments `(?#comment)`. [See here.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

I guess, the best you can do, is to use the `RegExp` constructor and write every line in e separate string and concatenate them (with comments between the strings):

```
RegExp(
    "foo" + // match a foo
    "bar" + // followed by a bar
    "$"     // at the end of the string
).test("somefoobar");
```

Comment: Any comments for the downvote?

Comment: This kind of solution I would expect from newbie, not you @m.buettner! Don't you have any better workaround ideas?

Comment: @Ωmega well, I guess it incurs less overhead than running a regex replace on every regex. Plus, what it is wrong with presenting the non-hack solution? At least this version allows for any strings in the comments without any caveats.

Comment: I never said it is wrong and your answer has been upvoted. I am just saying that I expected more then just plain solution...

Comment: @Ωmega well, sorry to disappoint you.

Comment: an alternate means of inline commenting that is supported cross browser by regexp in javascript is to use the suffix not present in conjunction with the # for comment.
``
`example:`
`/*The regexp*/ /a(?!#this is a comment that is ignored)/`
`/*The Test*/ /a(?!#this is a comment that is ignored)/.exec('apple') returns an array of 1 element ["ap"]`
``

Answer (score 2):

Other than using a zero-length sub-expression, it's not possible. Examples of "comments":

```
/[a-z](?!<-- Any letter)/
```

`(?!..)` is a negated look-ahead. It matches if the previous is not followed by the string within the parentheses. Since the thing between `(?!` and `)` is a real regular (sub)expression, you cannot use arbitrary characters unless escaped with a backslash

An alternative is to use the positive look-ahead:

```
/[a-z](?=|<-- Any letter)/
```

This look-ahead will always match, because obviously the `a-z` is also followed by an empty string.

Comment: @m.buettner `(?=|...)` is sufficieny. It means: *Match if it is `followed by ""` OR `followed by "..."`*. Obviously, the first statement is true, and therefore the look-ahead has no negative consequences.

Comment: well yeah the two (mine and your second variant) are equivalent and I posted my comment before you edited in the second variant ;).

Comment: The negative lookahead version is dangerous because there's always the chance, however small, that the string will contain the comment after the match and therefore fail to match.  The positive lookahead with the empty string is the way to go.

Comment: You could also do `(?:comment goes here){0}`, but that's tricky because the important bit that makes it a comment is the `{0}`, which goes at the end and therefore might be missed.

Comment: @MarkReed That's more error-prone/less readable, and uses more characters than the two look-ahead approaches in my answer. I upvoted your previous comment, because it's true (althouh the chances are slim, especially if the look-ahead is followed by something that contradicts the look-ahead itself).

Comment: @RobW I agree, which is why I said it was "tricky" and didn't give it as its own answer.  Just pointing out the alternative exists, if for no other reason than to help folks recognize that construct when they run across it, which I have...

Comment: Regex comment syntax allows `(?#c(o(m(m(e(n(t)`, but your solution with `(?=|c(o(m(m(e(n(t)` would NOT work, so it is not fully supported alternative.

Comment: @Ωmega I already mentioned the potential shortcomings of the methods in my answer. The string-based comments (as seen in your and m.buettriers answers) require escaping of backslashes and quotes, which does not contribute to the readability of a RegExp. On the other hand, m.buettriers answer allows for multi-line comments, which might lead to a better understandable RegExp (because each atomic part could be put on its own line).

Comment: @m.buettner - My latest update allows escaped `)`