# Commenting Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

I'm trying to comment regular expressions in JavaScript.

There seems to be many resources on how to *remove* comments from code using regex, but not actually how to *comment* regular expressions in JavaScript so they are easier to understand.

Comment: If you're looking for [something like Perl's `/x` modifier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/632795/139010), there is no such thing in JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting question. I split my regex to strings and comment the strings, then concat them into the RegExp. I would love to hear of a better way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't have a verbose mode for regular expression literals like some other langauges do.  You may find [this interesting, though](http://xregexp.com/).

In lieu of any external libraries, your best bet is just to use a normal string and comment that:

```
var r = new RegExp(
    '('      + //start capture
    '[0-9]+' + // match digit
    ')'        //end capture
); 
r.test('9'); //true
```

Comment: Interesting but the obvious limit is that it doesn't let you build regex literals.

Comment: What can you get with regex literals that you can't get with the "new RegExp()" syntax?

Comment: @plemarquand Escaping becomes a pain. When you embed a language in a string, you need to be considerate of its special characters. For example, `/s\/\d+/` becomes `'s\\/\\d+'`. Because of that, you need to be careful when building dynamically. Basically, the same trouble you have on the server-side with the language soup.

Answer (score 11):

While Javascript doesn't natively support multi-line and commented regular expressions, it's easy enough to construct something that accomplishes the same thing - use a function that takes in a (multi-line, commented) string and returns a regular expression from that string, sans comments and newlines.

The following snippet imitates the behavior of other flavors' `x` ("[extended](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html)") flag, which ignores all whitespace characters in a pattern as well as comments, which are denoted with `#`:

```js
function makeExtendedRegExp(inputPatternStr, flags) {
  // Remove everything between the first unescaped `#` and the end of a line
  // and then remove all unescaped whitespace
  const cleanedPatternStr = inputPatternStr
    .replace(/(^|[^\\])#.*/g, '$1')
    .replace(/(^|[^\\])\s+/g, '$1');
  return new RegExp(cleanedPatternStr, flags);
}


// The following switches the first word with the second word:
const input = 'foo bar baz';
const pattern = makeExtendedRegExp(String.raw`
  ^       # match the beginning of the line
  (\w+)   # 1st capture group: match one or more word characters
  \s      # match a whitespace character
  (\w+)   # 2nd capture group: match one or more word characters
`);
console.log(input.replace(pattern, '$2 $1'));
```

Ordinarily, to represent a backslash in a Javascript string, one must double-escape each literal backslash, eg `str = 'abc\\def'`. But regular expressions often use many backslashes, and the double-escaping can make the pattern much less readable, so when writing a Javascript string with many backslashes it's a good idea to use a `String.raw` template literal, which allows a single typed backslash to actually represent a literal backslash, without additional escaping.

Just like with the standard `x` modifier, to match an actual `#` in the string, just escape it first, eg

```
foo\#bar     # comments go here
```

```js
// this function is exactly the same as the one in the first snippet

function makeExtendedRegExp(inputPatternStr, flags) {
  // Remove everything between the first unescaped `#` and the end of a line
  // and then remove all unescaped whitespace
  const cleanedPatternStr = inputPatternStr
    .replace(/(^|[^\\])#.*/g, '$1')
    .replace(/(^|[^\\])\s+/g, '$1');
  return new RegExp(cleanedPatternStr, flags);
}


// The following switches the first word with the second word:
const input = 'foo#bar baz';
const pattern = makeExtendedRegExp(String.raw`
  ^       # match the beginning of the line
  (\w+)   # 1st capture group: match one or more word characters
  \#      # match a hash character
  (\w+)   # 2nd capture group: match one or more word characters
`);
console.log(input.replace(pattern, '$2 $1'));
```

Note that to match a literal space character (and not just *any* whitespace character), while using the `x` flag in any environment (including the above), you have to escape the space with a `\` first, eg:

```
^(\S+)\ (\S+)   # capture the first two words
```

If you want to frequently match space characters, this can get a bit tedious and make the pattern harder to read, similar to how double-escaping backslashes isn't very desirable. One possible (non-standard) modification to permit unescaped space characters would be to only strip out spaces at the beginning and end of a line, and spaces before a `#` comment:

```js
function makeExtendedRegExp(inputPatternStr, flags) {
  // Remove the first unescaped `#`, any preceeding unescaped spaces, and everything that follows
  // and then remove leading and trailing whitespace on each line, including linebreaks
  const cleanedPatternStr = inputPatternStr
    .replace(/(^|[^\\]) *#.*/g, '$1')
    .replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\n/gm, '');
  console.log(cleanedPatternStr);
  return new RegExp(cleanedPatternStr, flags);
}


// The following switches the first word with the second word:
const input = 'foo bar baz';
const pattern = makeExtendedRegExp(String.raw`
  ^             # match the beginning of the line
  (\w+) (\w+)   # capture the first two words
`);
console.log(input.replace(pattern, '$2 $1'));
```

Answer (score 5):

In several other languages (notably Perl), there's the special `x` flag. When set, the regexp ignores any whitespace and comments inside of it. Sadly, javascript regexps do not support the `x` flag.

Lacking syntax, the only way to leverage readability is convention. Mine is to add a comment before the tricky regular expression, containing it as if you've had the x flag. Example:

```
/*
  \+?     #optional + sign
  (\d*)   #the integeric part
  (       #begin decimal portion
     \.
     \d+  #decimal part
  )
 */
var re = /\+?(\d*)(\.\d+)/;
```

For more complex examples, you can see what I've done with the technique [here](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/blob/b5e38026fb3acd79b40a69a7e097dd3ca96e0b5c/source/plugins/substitution.js#L2) and [here](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/blob/b5e38026fb3acd79b40a69a7e097dd3ca96e0b5c/source/listeners.js#L71).

Comment: +1 for `#read above, I'm not repeating this crap` (yes, somebody follows your links).

Answer (score 4):

In 2021 we can do this using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which have [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) applied to it.

```js
VerboseRegExp `
    (
        foo*                  // zero or more foos
        (?: bar | baz )       // bar or baz
        quux?                 // maybe a quux
    )
    
    \s \t \r \n \[ \] \\ \/ \`

    H e l l o                 // invisible whitespace is ignored ...
    [ ]                       // ... unless you put it in a character class
    W o r l d !

    $ {}                      // Separate with whitespace to avoid interpolation!
`
`gimy`                        // flags go here

/*
returns the RegExp
/(foo*(?:bar|baz)quux?)\s\t\r\n\[\]\\\/\`Hello[ ]World!${}/gimy
*/
```

The implementation of `VerboseRegExp`:

```js
const VerboseRegExp = (function init_once () {
    const cleanupregexp = /(?<!\\)[\[\]]|\s+|\/\/[^\r\n]*(?:\r?\n|$)/g
    return function first_parameter (pattern) {
        return function second_parameter (flags) {
            flags = flags.raw[0].trim()
            let in_characterclass = false
            const compressed = pattern.raw[0].replace(
                cleanupregexp,
                function on_each_match (match) {
                    switch (match) {
                        case '[': in_characterclass = true; return match
                        case ']': in_characterclass = false; return match
                        default: return in_characterclass ? match : ''
                    }
                }
            )
            return flags ? new RegExp(compressed, flags) : new RegExp(compressed)
        }
    }
})()
```

See [Verbose Regular Expressions
in JavaScript](https://keleshev.com/verbose-regular-expressions-in-javascript) for what `.raw[0]` does.

Notice that, unlike regex literals, the Javascript parser will not cache this, so save the generated regexp in a variable if you reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [verbose-regexp](https://github.com/jribbens/verbose-regexp) package.

```js
import { rx } from 'verbose-regexp'

const dateTime = rx`
 (\d{4}) // year
 -       // separator
 (\d{2}) // month
`

// returns RegExp /(\d{4})-(\d{2})/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put a regular comment above the line with the regular expression in order to explain it.

You will have much more freedom.

Comment: How would a regular comment above the line help in this case:
`(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])$`
This is the regex for email

Comment: You put a multi-line comment above. And you explain it chunk per chunk (the same way as Explosion Pills suggests, but above. It is much more convenient if you need to modify the reg ex.).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You know [your regex for email is probably flawed](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/), right ?

Comment: @dystroy Hah :) I would never write a RegExp for email validating, I was illustrating that RegularExpressions get _really_ unreadable _really_ fast. This one is from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: …and you would not use such a regex at all.

Comment: +1 for the mail+regex. But to come back to the topic, I have been using above-regex-comments for a long time and I find it really efficient. This leaves space to fully describe what is intended and how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Perl's `/x` flag (allows whitespace and #comments) is a Javascript language proposal, but stuck at stage 1 (of 4) of the process.

The modifiers proposal, e.g. `/(?i:ignore case)normal/` now at stage 3 had the `x` flag removed from it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the pattern like @ExplosionPills's, but with Array joining and raw template literals for better readibility.

```js
var r = String.raw;
var re = new RegExp([
  r`\+?`,    // optional + sign
  r`(\d*)`,  // the integeric part
  r`(`,      // begin decimal portion
    r`\.`,
    r`\d+`,  // decimal part
  r`)`,
].join(''));
```