# Embed comments within JavaScript regex like in Perl

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

Is there any way to embed a comment in a JavaScript regex, like [you can do in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632795/how-do-you-comment-a-perl-regular-expression)?  I'm guessing there is not, but my searching didn't find anything stating you can or can't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't embed a comment in a regex literal.

You may insert comments in a string construction that you pass to the RegExp constructor :

```
var r = new RegExp(
    "\\b"   + // word boundary
    "A="    + // A=
    "(\\d+)"+ // what is captured : some digits
    "\\b"     // word boundary again
, 'i');       // case insensitive
```

But a regex literal is so much more convenient (notice how I had to escape the `\`) I'd rather separate the regex from the comments : just put some comments before your regex, not inside.

**EDIT 2018:** This question and answer are very old. EcmaScript now offers new ways to handle this, and more precisely [template strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings).

For example I now use [this simple utility](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs/rex.js) in node:

```
module.exports = function(tmpl){
    let [, source, flags] = tmpl.raw.toString()
    .replace(/\s*(\/\/.*)?$\s*/gm, "") // remove comments and spaces at both ends of lines
    .match(/^\/?(.*?)(?:\/(\w+))?$/); // extracts source and flags
    return new RegExp(source, flags);
}
```

which lets me do things like [this](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/78bab29a32c4ec2e6afa79b123685c1d58670c59/plugins/dice/plugin.js#L21) or [this](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/d3eb65628f50b2f01a8626b51b8b116953165560/libs/commands.js) or this:

```
const regex = rex`
    ^         // start of string
    [a-z]+    // some letters
    bla(\d+)
    $         // end
    /ig`;

console.log(regex); // /^[a-z]+bla(\d+)$/ig
console.log("Totobla58".match(regex)); // [ 'Totobla58' ]
```

Comment: As for code documentation, that's bad news. I would probably "unroll" a literal regexp in a multi-line comment and explain its pieces. One must not forget to update the comment with the expression however. What also speaks for literals is that they are created faster than via the RegExp() constructor: http://jsperf.com/creating-regular-expressions/4

Answer (score -2):

Now with [the grave backticky things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can do inline comments with a little finagling. Note that in the example below there are some assumptions being made about what won't appear in the strings being matched, especially regarding the whitespace. But I think often you can make intentional assumptions like that, if you write the `process()` function carefully. If not, there are probably creative ways to define the little "mini-language extension" to regexes in such a way as to make it work.

```
function process() {
  var regex = new RegExp("\\s*([^#]*?)\\s*#.*$", "mg");
  var output = "";
  while ((result = regex.exec(arguments[0])) !== null ){
    output += result[1];
  }
  return output;
}
var a = new RegExp(process `
    ^f    # matches the first letter f
    .*   # matches stuff in the middle
    h    # matches the letter 'h'
`);
console.log(a);
console.log(a.test("fish"));
console.log(a.test("frog"));
```

Here's [a codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqwoow?editors=0010)

Also, to the OP, just because I feel a need to say this, this is neato, but if your resulting code turns out just as verbose as the string concatenation or if it takes you 6 hours to figure out the right regexes and you are the only one on your team who will bother to use it, maybe there are better uses of your time...

I hope you know that I am only this blunt with you [because I value our friendship](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2027:9&version=NIV).

Comment: Thanks. Spending too much time making this work would indeed be a [grave mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).