# Time format validation regex, either military or AM/PM but not both

Tags: javascript, regex, time-format

I've got this regex here:

```
^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(:00)?(\s)?(AM|PM|am|pm)?$
```

It does an OK job. Allows stuff like `23:00:00` or `12:00 AM` or `1:00am`, etc.

Problem is it also allows stuff like `23:24 AM`.

What's the best way to modify this or append this to disallow AM/PM if the first set of digits is > 12?

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: Time validation is a complex thing. Leave it to a library.

Comment: Well I'm using this in javascript

Comment: It also allows `78:99:00 AM`

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/iY9mR7/2, does it suit your requirements?

Comment: I think that's the winner, stribizhev. I modified it a bit to allow seconds:

`^((?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9]))(\s)?([ap]m)?|([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$`

Comment: @Thom Watch out for leap seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?\d|1[012]):[0-5]\d(?::00)? ?[ap]m)|(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d(?::00)?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^
(?:                 : start non capturing group
  (?:               : start non capturing group
    (?:             : start non capturing group
      0?\d          : matches optional 0 followed by 1 digit
      |             : OR
      1[012]        : 1 followed by digit between 0 and 2
    )               : end group
    :               : literally :
    [0-5]\d         : digit between 0 and 5 followed by any digit
    (?::00)?        : optional 00 seconds
     ?              : optional space
    [ap]m           : am or pm
  )                 : end group 
  |                 : OR
  (?:               : start non capturing group
   [01]?\d          : 0 or 1 (optional) followed by any digit
   |                : OR
   2[0-3]           : 20 to 23
  )                 : end group
  :                 : literally :
  [0-5]\d           : digit between 0 and 5 followed by any digit
  (?::00)?          : optional 00 seconds
)                   : end group
$
```

Comment: @Biffen: It works because OP wants to have the seconds equal 00.

Comment: That's definitely an improvement. Thanks! I like the one  stribizhev linked to in a comment above as well.

Comment: If JS allowed VERBOSE regex, that would be really good, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: Have to give it to you for the detailed breakdown. Many thanks.

Comment: @stribizhev: Do you mean embeded comments? It's allowed in javascript, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19865112

Comment: I see, only in the constructor notation, as comments on several lines. I just meant the `x` option is not available, and then we cannot use the `?#` comments like in C#, PHP...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to solve the issue:

```
^((0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?)\s?([ap]m)?|([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?$
```

JS:

```
var re = /^((0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?)\s?([ap]m)?|([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?$/gmi;
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iY9mR7/6)

Note the use of `i` option (to enable case insensitive matching) and `m` to match whole lines.

This regex allows for minutes and seconds (seconds are optional).

Comment: Actually, you did not mention anything about the capturing groups, I did not care about them... But if you need to catch all the parts of the time values, I'd need to expand the minute and second capturing groups as you showed in the comment. I updated to make sure all the parts are now captured into groups.